# Get location of exception handler after an exception has occurred(in a .exe file) via Intel PinTool

Tags: exe, intel-pin

Sorry for the long POST :)

I would like to write a pintool for **.exe** files which on a exception does the following:

1. Prints the excepting instruction address.
2. Prints the address of the handler which will handle this exception.
3. Prints the address of the instruction where the program returns.

I have read all about windows SEH mechanism and I have good familiarity with intel pin-tool itself. To get going, I wrote the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void bar(){
        throw 20;
}
void foo(char *s, int a){
    printf(s,a);
}
int main(){
    try{
        bar();
    }
    catch(int e){
        foo("%d\n",e );
    }
}
```

Then I printed all the routines (that are called after main has been called) with their return addresses for this program using pintool. [Here](http://pastebin.com/raw/Jh0wFYcR) is the list:

Then I read up the documentation of these routines. I thought that the arguments of these routines might contain the information I need. But all in vain. `RtlRaiseException` arguments did gave me access to the `ExceptionRecord` structure but its `ExceptionAddress` field contains the starting address of `RaiseException` instead of an address of `bar`.

And I was unable to find any way to get the Exception Handler location which will handle the `throw`.

Any help is appreciated; thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer directly aimed at a PIN solution but rather a help on how to find the handler.

Below is the interesting part of the code compiled without optimization (I added a `printf` below the `bar` function so the handler was not too close to `bar`; code compiled with VS 2015):

```
CPU Disasm
Address    Command                                Comments
011D1071   CALL bar                               ; [bar
011D1076   PUSH OFFSET 011D2110                   ; ASCII "you wont see me..."
011D107B   CALL printf                            ; [printf
011D1080   ADD ESP,4
011D1083   JMP SHORT 011D109C
011D1085   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]          ; Handler start
011D1088   PUSH EAX
011D1089   PUSH OFFSET 011D2124                   ; ASCII "%d"
011D108E   CALL foo                               ; [foo
```

Here's the code for the bar() function:

```
CPU Disasm
Address    Command                                Comments
011D1000 b PUSH EBP                               ; TestCppException.bar(void)
011D1001   MOV EBP,ESP
011D1003   PUSH ECX
011D1004   MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],14
011D100B   PUSH OFFSET _TI1H                      ; /Arg2 = TestCppException._TI1H
011D1010   LEA EAX,[EBP-4]                        ; |
011D1013   PUSH EAX                               ; |Arg1
011D1014   CALL _CxxThrowException                ; \VCRUNTIME140._CxxThrowException
011D1019   MOV ESP,EBP
011D101B   POP EBP
011D101C   RETN
```

C++ exception are different beasts than other exceptions (access violation, divide by 0, etc.) as there are a lot of things going on under the hood before reaching the handler (the catch part).

As you have seen, a C++ exception is raised using:

- [__CxxThrowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff795730.aspx)
- [RaiseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680552(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [RtlRaiseException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh829883(v=vs.85).aspx)

When `RtlRaiseException` is called, the Exception record looks like this:

```
CPU Stack
Address   Value                Comments
0018FAF8  |E06D7363    ; ExceptionCode=E06D7363
0018FAFC  |00000001    ; Flags=EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE
0018FB00  |00000000    ; pExceptionRecord=NULL
0018FB04  |7736DAA0    ; ExceptionAddress=KERNELBASE.RaiseException
0018FB08  |00000003    ; Nparm=3
0018FB0C  |19930520    ; exception version identifier
0018FB10  |0018FBA4    ; pObject
0018FB14  |011D2638    ; _ThrowInfo*
```

- The **exception code** `0xE06D7363` identifies a C++ exception (same code for all C++ exception).
- **Flags** is set to `EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE` because C++ exceptions do not support continuation (the code can’t continue execution at the point where the exception occurred).
- **pExceptionRecord** is NULL because there’s no exception chaining in CPP exception.
- The **ExceptionAddress** is `RaiseException` because it is not “directly” your code that raises the exception, but the system does it for you (i.e: it’s not like if you had a divide by 0 which can be pinpointed to a very specific assembly instruction; here the system raises the exception for you, and it raises it at RaiseException).
- There are 3 parameters to this exception record :

  - The first one is an exception identifier (this is undocumented, but probably means that this is a VC6 style exception).
  - pObject is a pointer to the thrown object (in our case this is a pointer to the integer 20)
  - Finally a `_ThrowInfo` structure (the same as the argument passed to `_CxxThrowException`) which is used by the system, more precisely the exception dispatcher, to see which handler can catch this exception.

From this point, we have the “usual” SEH stuff where the system dispatches the exception and search for the right SEH handler. In our example, “which catch block can catch an int”.

It happens that the last SEH in the chain can handle the thrown int.

Here’s an assembly view of the SEH:

```
CPU Disasm
Address    Command                           Comments
00CA1D91   MOV EAX,OFFSET 011D2580        ; pointer to __ehfuncinfo
00CA1D96   JMP __CxxFrameHandler3            ; Jump to VCRUNTIME140.__CxxFrameHandler
```

We only have a structure passed (through `eax` register) to a function named `__CxxFrameHandler3`.

The structure, named `__ehfuncinfo` looks like this:

```
struct ehfuncinfo1200 //_s_ESTypeList
{
  /* 0x00 */  uint32_t        magic : 30;
  /* 0x04 */  ehstate_t       unwindtable_size;
  /* 0x08 */  unwindtable *   unwindtable;
  /* 0x0C */  size_t          tryblocktable_size;
  /* 0x10 */  tryblock *      tryblocktable;
  /* 0x14 */  size_t          _size;
  /* 0x18 */  void *          _;
/* … snip … */
};
```

In our case we have:

```
CPU 
Address    Value       Comments
011D2580   19930522    ; magic
011D2584   00000002    ; unwind table size 
011D2588   011D25A4    ; unwind table
011D258C   00000001    ; try block table size
011D2590   011D25B4    ; try block table
011D2594   00000000
011D2598   00000000
```

An entry in the `try block table` looks like this:

```
struct tryblock
{
  ehstate_t   trylow;
  ehstate_t   tryhigh;
  ehstate_t   catchhigh;
  int         ncatches;
  ehandler *  catchsym;

  /* snip */
};
```

Below are the value from our example:

```
CPU Stack
Address   Value      Comments
011D25B4   00000000  
011D25B8   00000000
011D25BC   00000001  
011D25C0   00000001 ; ncatches
011D25C4   011D25C8 ; catchsym
```

The `catchsym` field is a `ehandler` structure:

```
/// This type represents the catch clause
struct ehandler
{
//  union { uint32_t  adjectives; void * ptr; };
  uint32_t isconst      : 1; /* + 00 */
  uint32_t isvolatile   : 1;
  uint32_t isunaligned  : 1;
  uint32_t isreference  : 1;

  const type_info *   typeinfo; /* + 04 */
  ptrdiff_t           eobject_bpoffset; // 0 = no object (catch by type)
  generic_function_t *  handler; /* + 0x0C */

  /* snip */
};
```

**Note**: the `handler` field is the address of the catch block!

And the value:

```
CPU Stack
Address   Value        Comments
011D25C8   00000000    ; 
011D25CC   011D3030    ; Typeinfo (OFFSET TestCppException.int `RTTI Type Descriptor')
011D25D0   FFFFFFEC    
011D25D4   011D1085    ; Handler entry point
```

And in our case the handler field points to the precise location of the catch block:

```
CPU Disasm
Address    Command                            Comments
011D1085   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]      ; handler start
011D1088   PUSH EAX
011D1089   PUSH OFFSET 011D2124               ; ASCII "%d"
011D108E   CALL foo                           ;
```

---

**Summary**

If an exception occurs (see [Exception API in PIN Manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/76991/Pin/html/group__EXCEPTION__API.html))

- Check the exception ocde: if it's `0xE06D7363` then it's a C++ exception
- Wait for `__CxxFrameHandler3` to be called (technically it is a JMP to this function, not a CALL)
- Check the `eax` register on `__CxxFrameHandler3` entry.
- The `eax`register is a pointer to a `__ehfuncinfo` structure.
- Follow all structures up to the `handler` field of the `ehandler` structure.

  - the `handler` field is the address of the `catch block`

---

Some good pointers on the subject:

- [Reversing Microsoft Visual C++ Part I: Exception Handling](http://www.openrce.org/articles/full_view/21)
- [Compiler Internals - How Try/Catch/Throw are Interpreted by the Microsoft Compiler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175482/Compiler-Internals-How-Try-Catch-Throw-are-Interpr)
- [some undocumented structures for C++ exception handling](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:BrCmO3ghQooJ:ontl.googlecode.com/svn-history/r171/trunk/ntl/nt/exception.hxx)

---

**Pintool code**

```cpp
/* ===================================================================== */
/* This example demonstrates finding a function by name on Windows.      */
/* ===================================================================== */

#include "pin.H"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

/*
* C++ exception structures
*/

// This type represents the catch clause
typedef struct _ehandler
{
    //  union { uint32_t  adjectives; void * ptr; };
    uint32_t            adjectives;         /* + 0x00 */
    const type_info *   typeinfo;           /* + 0x04 */
    ptrdiff_t           eobject_bpoffset;   /* + 0x08 */
    void*               handler;            /* + 0x0C */ 
    /* snip */
} ehandler;

typedef struct _tryblock
{
    uint32_t   trylow;
    uint32_t   tryhigh;
    uint32_t   catchhigh;
    int         ncatches;
    ehandler *  catchsym;
    /* snip */
} tryblock;

typedef struct ehfuncinfo1200 //_s_ESTypeList
{
    /* 0x00 */  uint32_t        magic : 30;
    /* 0x04 */  uint32_t       unwindtable_size;
    /* 0x08 */  void *   unwindtable;
    /* 0x0C */  size_t          tryblocktable_size;
    /* 0x10 */  tryblock *      tryblocktable;
    /* 0x14 */  size_t          _size;
    /* 0x18 */  void *          _;
    /* snip */
} ehfuncinfo;

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Global Variables */
/* ===================================================================== */

std::ofstream TraceFile;

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Commandline Switches */
/* ===================================================================== */

KNOB<string> KnobOutputFile(KNOB_MODE_WRITEONCE, "pintool",
    "o", "check_handler.out", "specify trace file name");

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Print Help Message                                                    */
/* ===================================================================== */

INT32 Usage()
{
    cerr << "This tool produces a trace of calls to RtlAllocateHeap.";
    cerr << endl << endl;
    cerr << KNOB_BASE::StringKnobSummary();
    cerr << endl;
    return -1;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Analysis routines                                                     */
/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Before(CHAR * name, ADDRINT RegValue)
{
    TraceFile << "At function entry (" << name << "); EAX: " << hex << RegValue << endl;

    // eax is a pointer to ehfuncinfo struct
    ehfuncinfo* funcinfo = reinterpret_cast<ehfuncinfo*>(RegValue);

    // get the tryblock table from ehfuncinfo
    tryblock* tryb = funcinfo->tryblocktable;

    // get ehandler struct from try block
    ehandler* ehand = tryb->catchsym;

    // from ehandler structure, get handler address
    void* handler = ehand->handler;

    // save it to file
    TraceFile << "Handler Address: " << hex << handler << endl;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Instrumentation routines                                              */
/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Image(IMG img, VOID *v)
{
    // Walk through the symbols in the symbol table.
    //
    for (SYM sym = IMG_RegsymHead(img); SYM_Valid(sym); sym = SYM_Next(sym))
    {
        string undFuncName = PIN_UndecorateSymbolName(SYM_Name(sym), UNDECORATION_NAME_ONLY);

        //  Find function.
        if (undFuncName == "__CxxFrameHandler3")
        {
            std::cout << "OK! found __CxxFrameHandler3" << std::endl;

            RTN allocRtn = RTN_FindByAddress(IMG_LowAddress(img) + SYM_Value(sym));

            if (RTN_Valid(allocRtn))
            {
                // Instrument to print the input argument value and the return value.
                RTN_Open(allocRtn);

                RTN_InsertCall(allocRtn, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)Before,
                    IARG_ADDRINT, "__CxxFrameHandler3",
                    IARG_REG_VALUE, REG::REG_EAX,
                    IARG_END);

                RTN_Close(allocRtn);
            }
        }
    }
}

/* ===================================================================== */

VOID Fini(INT32 code, VOID *v)
{
    TraceFile.close();
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* Main                                                                  */
/* ===================================================================== */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initialize pin & symbol manager
    PIN_InitSymbols();
    if (PIN_Init(argc, argv))
    {
        return Usage();
    }

    // Write to a file since cout and cerr maybe closed by the application
    TraceFile.open(KnobOutputFile.Value().c_str());
    TraceFile << hex;
    TraceFile.setf(ios::showbase);

    // Register Image to be called to instrument functions.
    IMG_AddInstrumentFunction(Image, 0);
    PIN_AddFiniFunction(Fini, 0);

    // Never returns
    PIN_StartProgram();

    return 0;
}

/* ===================================================================== */
/* eof */
/* ===================================================================== */
```

---

**Output**

```
At function entry (__CxxFrameHandler3); EAX: 0xcc2580
Handler Address: 0x00cc1085
```

Both match the given code (minus offsets due to ASLR):

```
 MOV EAX,OFFSET 011D2580        ; pointer to __ehfuncinfo

 ...

011D1085   MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-14]  ; Handler start
```

---

Comment: I could not find `__ehfuncinfo` structure under `windows.h` so I tried get a pointer to `try block table` directly using `*((unsigned*)((unsigned char)PIN_GetContextReg(ctx,REG_EAX) + 0x10))` in an analysis routine called when `_CxxFrameHandler3` is called. But the value I got was `2` which is certainly incorrect . What is the problem ?

Comment: @Nishant : those structures aren't undocumented and not meant to be available to programmers ; they aren't even defined in headers and are directly embedded in the compiler itself. I updated my answer with a pintool code.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to know where the catch code ends ?

Comment: @Nishant No you can't know the end of the catch block. It's only known at compile time and that information is lost on the final binary.

Comment: Thank you , It works perfect for C++ exceptions. Do you have any ideas for C exceptions like `__try`

Comment: @Nishant You're welcome o/ ; Yes, but that'd probably make another (long) answer.

Comment: I really need this for all types of exceptions, so if you do not want to write another long answer, could you give me some pointers.